# Problems measuring complexity in python's scripts

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have problems measuring complexity with python. Given the next two scripts:

```
1 def program1(L):              
2 multiples = []                
3 for x in L:                   
4     for y in L:               
5         multiples.append(x*y) 
6 return multiples        



1 def program3(L1, L2):
2 intersection = []
3 for elt in L1:
4     if elt in L2:
5         intersection.append(elt)
6 return intersection
```

In the first one the best case (minimum steps to run the sript) is two considering an empty list `L` so are executed only the second and the sixth lines. The solution for the best case scenario: is `2`.

In the worst case scenario `L` is a long list it goes through the loop for `x` in `L` `n` times.

The inner loop has three operations (assignment of a value to `y`, `x*y`, and list appending). So the inner loop executes `3*n` times on each iteration of the outer loop. Thus the nested loop structure is executed `n * (3*n + 1) = 3*n**2 + n` times. Adding the second and the sixth line we get the solution `3n²+n+2`.

But my question is: **Where does comes from the number `1` in `n(3n+1)`?**

According to me the solution is `n(3n)+2 = 3n²+2` vs the right answer `n(3n+1)+2 = 3n²+n+2`.

Meanwhile in the second one the worst case scenario is `n²+2n+2` but I don't understand why there is a quadratic term if there is only one loop.

Comment: *"there is only one loop"* - `elt in L2` iterates too.

Comment: That's an odd interpretation of 'best case' for the first program.

Comment: Why do you say that? It is wrong the interpretation of best case?

Comment: I don't knew it was iterative D:

Comment: The `+1` might be the assignment to `x` in the outer loop. The "best case" is usually considered to be "the best case for a given input size". For the first program, it doesn't matter at all, but for the second program, there are "good" and "bad" choices for `L1` and `L2`. Consider what `in` actually has to do.

Answer (score 2):

According to you, there are three instructions in the innermost (`y`) loop of `program1`.

1. Assign to y.
2. Compute x*y.
3. Append to list.

By that same logic, there is one instruction in the outmost (`x`) loop:

1. Assign to x.
2. Perform inmost loop, see above.

That would make the outer loop:

```
n * (1 {assign to x} + n * 3 {assign, multiply, append})
```

Or:

```
n * (1 + 3n)
```

Adding the init/return instructions gives:

```
2 + n + 3n²
```

In `program2`, there is a similar situation with a "hidden loop":

```
2 instructions for init/return, plus ...
```

Then you run `for elt in L1`, which is going to be `n` iterations (n is size of L1). Your inner code is an `if` statement. In the worst case, the if body always runs. In the best case, it never runs.

The `if` condition is testing `elt in L2`, which is going to run an iterative function, `type(L2).__contains__()` on L2. The simple case will be an *O(m)* operation, where `m` is the length of L2. It is possible that `L2` is not a list but some type where the `in` operation does not require a linear scan. For example, it might be a B-tree, or a dict, or a set, or who knows what? So you could assume that the best-case scenario is that `elt in L2` is *O(1)* and the answer is no, while the worst-case is that `elt in L2` is *O(m)* and the answer is yes.

```
Best case:  2 + n * (1 {assign to elt} + 1 {search L2})
Best case if L2 is a list: 2 + n * (1 {assign to elt} + m {search L2})
Worst case: 2 + n * (1 {assign to elt} + m {search L2} + 1 {append})
```

Which gives you **2 + 2n** best case, **2 + n + nm** best case if L2 is a list, and **2 + 2n + nm** worst case.

You may be inclined to treat `m` as equal to `n`. That's your call, but if you're counting assignment statements, I'd argue against it.